# Heroku + Addons Provider Alpha Stage

Tags: heroku, add-on

I've been working for a new add-on of Heroku, currently it was an alpha stage now. So currently, I can't add the add-on on my App that I also created since there is no button for me to add it. Can someone point me to some resources wherein it can help me to figure it out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't find the button to add add-on in alpha stage also. Seems that in alpha stage it is not seen in general add-on list and there are no other lists available.

However, command line interface (CLI) worked:

```
$ heroku addons:add your_alpha_addon_name --app your_application_name
```

As for the materials regarding add-on development:

- Official provider resources: https://addons.heroku.com/provider/resources/
- [Heroku Add-on Providers Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/heroku-add-on-providers)

Answer (score 0):

If you login with your add-on provider account or as alpha user, you can point directly to the add-on heroku page, like
https://addons.heroku.com/YOUR-ADDON
The you can add the add-on to one of your apps

New alpha users can be created if you login as provider and go to your add-on provider portal
https://addons.heroku.com/marketplace/addons/YOUR-ADDON/edit